# Number of paths in a 3 dimensional grid with some restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider traveling from $(-1,2,0)$ to $(1,3,7)$ in $\mathbb Z^3$. The only possible moves are $H$ which corresponds to incrementing $x$ by $1$ and $V$ which increments $y$ by $1$ and $A$ which increments $z$ by $1$. The total possible paths is known to be $\dfrac{10!}{2!1!7!}=360$. I want to determine among these paths those that start by exactly an even number of $A$ moves. So if I start by $AA$ the third move should be $V$ or $H$ which leaves two possiblities ($2H$ and $5A$ )or ($1H\; and \; 1V \; and \; 5A$)  so we get $2*(\dfrac{7!}{2!5!}+\dfrac{7!}{1!1!5!})$ next we do the same if we sart by $4A$ and then by $6A$. We find the following possible number of paths starting exactly by an even number of $A$:
$$2*(\frac{7!}{2!5!}+\dfrac{7!}{1!1!5!})+2*(\frac{5!}{2!3!}+\dfrac{5!}{1!1!3!})+2*(\frac{3!}{2!1!}+\dfrac{3!}{1!1!1!})=204$$
Is my computation correct? and can we understand from this problem that the case starting with $0$ $A$ should be also considered, as $0$ is an even number or is it usually understood in this kind of problems that the zero case is not included?

Comment: I don't think you should have the factors of $2$ in front of each parenthesized expression. (I.e., I think $204$ double counts the quantity you want.) I don't know whether the case of $0$ A's at the beginning should be counted.  Personally I would count that case, but I can't guess the intent of the problem poser. [By the way, if you do count that case with your factors of $2$, you will find that your number of sequences exceeds $360$, which is clearly incorrect.]

Comment: Ok so we have a number $$(\frac{7!}{2!5!}+\dfrac{7!}{1!1!5!})+(\frac{5!}{2!3!}+\dfrac{5!}{1!1!3!})+(\frac{3!}{2!1!}+\dfrac{3!}{1!1!1!})=102$$